# Maintaining LM2596 output voltage with switch

Tags: voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply, zener

I'm simulating an LM2596 DC-DC voltage regulator to give me a 5-volt output given a 5 ohm load (1 amp). The circuit is shown below:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwDHoH.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

In my simulation, after throwing the switch after the LM2596 has reached a stable voltage, the load voltage after the switch spiked to around 6.6 V before stabilizing to around 4.968 volts. I'm trying to mitigate that spike by adding a capacitor and a zener diode before the switch in order to maintain the load voltage at approximately 5 volts. Without D3 and only C5, it spikes to 5.5 V before settling to 4.968 V, and with D3 and C5 together, it gets reduced down to 5.04 V and settles to 4.965 V in a matter of milliseconds. Is this a good method at 'stabilizing' the load voltage when using a regulator and a switch? What are some drawbacks of using a zener diode in this method?

EDIT: The SPICE model I'm using in my simulations is an adjustable regulator which I set to 5 V using a voltage divider, but the IC I plan to use is fixed at a 5 volt output. That's what I'm showcasing in my schematic, a fixed-voltage regulator.

EDIT: I'm basing my circuit off of TI's recommended schematic, a fixed output voltage regulator. The image is below, but I used TI's webbench tool to get the values shown in my schematic above.

[image: Recommended Schematic]

EDIT:  Below is a simulation of the output DC waveform at the load. Using a 15 V input, I simulated four different variations of the LM2596. The first plot shows the recommended datasheet's parts while the other three show Webbench's part suggestions with and without a post-ripple filter as well as a small 10 nF capacitor on the load at the last plot.

[image]

Comment: ??? *before settling to 5.968 V* ???

Comment: @Andyaka Sorry, my bad. Fixed it. Typo.

Comment: Can you add waveforms to see what is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Is this a good method at 'stabilizing' the load voltage when using a
>   regulator and a switch?*

All your problems come from the extra LC you have added namely L2 and C4+C5. Together they convert a low pass filter into hyper resonant tuned circuit that resonates at 3.85 kHz and has a Q factor of nearly 70. Any step change in the load will cause significant ringing and over-voltage problems on your output.

It seems you are going down the road of setting a spider to catch a fly then sending in the bird to catch the spider. You need to step back and work out why you have introduced L2.

BTW - don't try using this within the feedback loop of the switching chip because you'll just make an oscillator.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. L2 and C4 are part of a optional post-ripple filter circuit suggested by TI. I introduced it to reduce the ripple at the output, but seeing as how you said it might be part of the problem, I'm running some sims to see if TI's suggested circuit is better than what I am running.

Comment: I ran some more tests with and without the optional ripple filter that I mentioned, and it seems the the addition of the filter smooths out the voltage at the output load, reducing the ripple voltage at the output. Without that filter, with nominal voltage being 5 volts, the output voltage oscillates between 4.23 and 5.28 V. With the filter, it goes down to

Comment: Sorry, pressed wrong button.With the filter, the output voltage spikes to 6.53 V, but after 1.3 ms, it goes down to between 4.97 and 4.96 volts. Perhaps it's my SPICE model, but is the fixed LM2596 known for ripple voltage at the output? Also, what were you going to say at the end there?

Comment: How odd. Maybe it was a rogue sentence I’d started that got lost along the way.

Comment: Ripple voltage is a feature of buck regulators as with any switching regulators.

Comment: I posted my simulation circuit, showing comparisons between the original recommended values in the datasheet and what was calculated using TI's webbench tool. You can see in the 2nd and 3rd plot how the ripple-filter makes a difference, though those plots are using values from TI's webbench tool. What I am trying to reduce is the sudden spike due to the switch as shown when the switch turns on.

Comment: Those waveforms look like start up waveforms - can you explain what was the role of the load-switch - was it closed all the time or did it close only at the point where the waveforms properly begin? Or do the waveforms show the overall switch on response with the load-switch always closed?

Comment: The switches were open at first, and they close when the simulation time reaches a certain time, here 2 ms (arbitrary). I gave the IC some time to climb to a steady voltage, and then I introduce the load. What the waveforms show is the load output voltage from the entire simulation time from t=0. Thus, you have a 0 V output until t=2ms, when the switch closes.

Comment: OK, you may need a speed up capacitor across the feedback resistor (3.065 kohm). Try 10 pF to start with and then it should begin to improve gradually. Shouldn't take long to do in your sim.

Comment: Thanks. That capacitor across the feedback sped things up. Running some more sims and changing out some parts, I'm starting to think that the optional filter is screwing things up, like you said. Changing out that catch diode and increasing the output capacitor makes a significant difference. Question I'm worried about now is how much flexibility is there when choosing parts? The changes I'm making kind of go against what TI recommends, but they work in simulation, and it's due to cost and size. Is that necessarily a problem when designing with buck regulators?

Comment: The trouble is that the TI part was developed by National Semiconductor and TI bought them up probably nearly ten years ago and, of course there may be a lot of contradictory stuff around. There are better regulators around that have improved ripple voltage because they operate at higher switching speeds. Hey, the 2596 was king in its day and I was really pleased to use them back in the late 80s/90s.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I guess I'm just overly worried about choosing the wrong parts and making my efforts a waste, though I guess that this comes with the territory being a first draft and all. The simulation looks tolerable for my needs so perhaps it might work for now. I wasn't aware that this part is so old.

Comment: [here's](http://wiki.sunfounder.cc/images/f/f8/LM2596_datasheet.PDF) a Nat semi 2002 data sheet but, in it's earlier through pinned guise it was knocking around in the mid 90s if not earlier. The National Semiconductor "simple switcher" range began in 1990 - I've just checked - so you are using 30 year old tech with possibly a few advancements. I'm not rubbishing it (as I would certainly do if anyone proposed to use an LM741 op-amp) but, along the course of 30 years there'll be good and bad info. If you are happy about the model AND it seems to do the job then use it. Did you try 10pF?

Comment: Yes, an addition of a 10 pF capacitor across the feedback and the output (in parallel with the feedback resistor in my simulation that's not 1K) aided in my simulation by speeding things up. Thank you for that, though ideally, I'll be using the 5V-fixed version, so I would just directly connect the output pin to the feedback pin like on the datasheet. I went with it as it seemed to suit my needs as a power supply, and it's affordable.

Answer (score 0):

You definitely need larger capacitors at the input. Start with 100uF and see how much it helps, then 220uF, then 470uF.
 Your C3 also seems small.
Finally, you should take the feedback from the output (at C4), not before it.

EDIT: I have re-read a part of your question and realized I had missed the part about the switch(ing) causing the problem. DOH!
Try adding some small capacitor (like 100nF to 10uF, see what range of values works) at the output AFTER the switch, NEXT to the load. I am suspecting switch/contact bounce and lead inductance.

Also, you shouldn't stress too much about simulations, as they often show a problem that isn't there in a real-world circuit, or they miss a problem that IS there in the real world.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was basing my circuit off of TI's recommended layout, whose values were chosen thanks to TI's webbench tool. I think I see what you mean about taking the output at C4, and I'll run some sims to see how that changes things.

Comment: I ran some sims based on what you said, and taking the feedback at C4 caused the output voltage to oscillate from 4.996 V to 5.09V. Taking the output at C3 produced a smoother output (with almost no oscillation) at around 4.97 V. Adjusting the value of C3 given my current values seems to cause distortion at the output even when I increase it to a larger value.

Comment: Just now I have re-read a part of your question and realized I had missed the part about the switch causing the problem. DOH! Try adding some small capacitor (like 100nF to 10uF, see what range of values works) at the output AFTER the switch, NEXT to the load. I am suspecting switch/contact bounce and lead inductance.

Comment: I posted my simulation circuit, showing comparisons between the original recommended values in the datasheet and what was calculated using TI's webbench tool. Results when adding a 10 nF capacitor at the output is shown at the last plot. It seemed to have a negligible effect when viewed with the parts before.

Comment: 10nF is very small for a 1A circuit, but it does have a noticeable effect. Try 100nF, 1uF and 10uF. It is also important what type/chemistry of the capacitor you're using at higher values. Electrolytics are slow, while ceramics can ring, so you could also combine a 100nF-1uF ceramic with a 10uF electrolytic. Finally, try increasing the C4 or Cout to 470uF and parallel it with a 0.1uF-1uF ceramic. You will often see up to 3 or even 4 different value capacitors paralleled to prevent ringing and because they have different pulse and high-frequency responses.